# for loop syntax error or if statement syntax error in java?

Tags: java, arraylist, syntax

This a very straight forward problem, but I have this method, and I think nothing is wrong with it, but for some reason it doesn't work. It compiles, but I expect to get a print out in the cmd that the food is added to the list.This method is only called when you type the word "food," the name of a food, and a double (calories per serving). Basically, it's storing the food names and the food calories per servings in an ArrayList called foodList.

The first if statement is for the program to check if you're trying to add a food already added in the list by comparing the food names in the list. If the for loop gets a hit, then it automatically recognizes it as the user wanting to update the calories of the said food.

The else if statement checks if c (servings) is equal to 0, which then proceeds to add the food into the list as well as its said calories.

The last else statement is self explanatory. If a negative servings is inputed, then it tells the user.

However, upon running the program, the code doesn't work. Any fixes, or maybe some syntax errors I might have not noticed? Thanks!

```
public String addFood( String n, double c) {
    for (int x = 0; x < foodList.size(); x++) {
        if (n.equals(foodList.get(x).getFoodName())) {
            currentFood.updateCalories(c);
        } else if (c > 0) {
            foodList.add(new Food (n,c));
            System.out.println("Added Food " + n + " with " + c + " kcal.");
        } else if (c < 0) {
            System.out.println("Negative calories detected. Please try again.");
        }
    }
```

return foodName;
}

Comment: "Doesn't work" doesn't give us a lot of information - please show expected output, and either actual output or the text of the error you're getting.

Comment: That said, you're running this check on *every* element of the list - so if you have `"apples"`, `"bananas"` and `"long pork"` on your list, then when you try to update the calories for `"bananas"` you will also add `"bananas"` to the list twice, as it does not equal `"apples"` or `"long pork"`. (Also, what if `c == 0`?`)

Comment: @EdwardPeters, but doesn't this only happen if we find the same name in the foodList?

Comment: So your first `if` block is checking if the food you're searching for is the food *at this index*. The other conditions are therefor checked if it is not the food at *this* index, even if it's the food at some other index.

Comment: Your code doesn't compile. You have one closing brace more than opening braces.

Comment: This is a variation of a bug I see here pretty often - `for{if...else...}`, where the programmer only intended the `else` block to run if the `if` statement *never* fire.

Comment: Probably not your immediate problem, but when you add a food F to the list (and set its calories to C)  then you'll increase the size of the list, and assuming F was added at the end, you'll encounter F again, thus 'updating' its calories again.

Comment: Oh, right, that's the other common bug pattern - operating on a list as a whole while from inside a block of code that's iterating over the list. Usually (not always) operations on individual elements should be nested in your iteration block, and operations on the list as a whole should be arranged sequentially.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I suppose your program is intended to do is to look for a food, and do different things depending on whether it's been seen before.  It may be helpful to consider 'look for food' as a separate step.  Here I add a 'helper method' to do that.

```
private int findFood(String name) {
    for (int x = 0; x < foodList.size(); x++) {
        if (name.equals(foodList.get(x).getFoodName())) {
            return x;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}

public String addFood(String name, double cals) {
       int index = findFood(name);
       if (index >= 0) {  // found
            currentFood.updateCalories(cals);
       } else if (cals > 0) {
            foodList.add(new Food(name, cals));
            System.out.println("Added Food " + name + " with " + cals + " kcal.");
        } else if (cals < 0) {
            System.out.println("Negative calories detected. Please try again.");
        }
    }
```

The overall lessons here are (a) you're not obliged to cram all the logic into a single method, and (b) breaking the logic down often helps clarify what is going on.

(The function of 'currentFood' seems obscure to me, since it was not modified by anything in your original code.  Should 'currentFood' be set to the food found at index 'x'?)